# Need help writing a regex for usernames

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey so I'm looking for a regrex pattern that:

- Allows for only two or one `_` in a row but no more, can end start and have the `_` in between
- Max 20, min 3 characters
- Allows for only one period in a row and can't start or end in a period
- Accepts A-Z and 1-9

Some examples of passes and fails are:

```
.test #fail
_test #pass
_.test #pass
__test #pass
test_ #pass
te_.st #pass
te.st #pass
..test #fail
```

So far I have `^[\w](?!.*?\.{2})(?!.*?_{2})[\w.]{1,28}$`, which works for everything but detecting the `__` between and at the end of the words. Any help would be appreciated! This has been hurting my brain for hours

Comment: Sometimes it makes things substantially easier to just use 2-3 regexes instead of trying to get it all into one.

Comment: `\w` includes `0` is zero allowed? Also are only capitals allowed?

Comment: How would I go about changing it into 2-3 regexes? Also sorry, its 0-9 and capitals are allowed

Comment: For, example, if all your existing regex lacks is to detect the `__`, just add a second regex for that and do `str.match(regex1) and ! str.match(regex2)` or similar

Comment: IMO it's also more readable to do it that way, though not as fun :P

Comment: I think `(?=^[.]|[.]$|.{21,}|.{,2}|_{3,}|[.]{2,}|^[^a-zA-Z0-9._]+$)` gets the inverse, so could just do a non-match with that. https://regex101.com/r/IDcQOw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Allows for only one period in a row and can't start or end in a period

Negative lookahead for `^\.`, `\.$`, and `\.\.` from the beginning of the string

> Allows for only two or one _ in a row but no more, can end start and have the _ in between

Negative lookahead for `__` from the beginning of the string

> Max 20, min 3 characters

After the other logic is implemented, match and consume 3-20 of the allowed characters

```
^(?!.*___|\.|.*\.$|.*\.\.)[a-z1-9_.]{3,20}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/TUjY13/2

- `^` - From start of string:
- `(?!.*___|\.|.*\.$|.*\.\.)` - Make sure match doesn't:

  - `.*___` - contain triple underscores
  - `\.` - start with a `.`
  - `.*\.$` - end with a `.`
  - `.*\.\.` - contain double periods
- `[a-z1-9_.]{3,20}` - Match 3-20 characters in the string body using all allowed characters (case-insensitive)

Comment: wow, thank you for such a great explanation and quick response, much appreciated!

Comment: @BananaGuy18 You should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sorry :p brand new to overflow

Comment: I think you can also omit the first lookahead and repeat the character class with the quantifier instead `^(?!.*___|\.|.*\.$|.*\.\.)[a-z1-9_.]{3,20}$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird You're completely right, I originally went with repeated character sets for the `.` logic, but then realized it was too repetitive and forgot to refactor the length check into the consuming token.